# Asset filtered out and will not be served rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( login.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

I ge the above error when i try to run my application.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "applicatin", "login" %>
```

I don't see any file name `asests.rb` in `config/initializers`.

Comment: is that meant to be `applicatin` as opposed to `application`?  Also is that meant to say `asests.rb` or `assets.rb` after "I don't see any file name"?

Comment: You need to create the `config/initializers/assets.rb` file if it's not there already.  Try creating it, adding the line it tells you to add and then restarting.  Ie doing what it told you to do :)

Comment: `config.assets.precompile`  available in `environments/production.rb` and `environments/test.rb` or `environments/development.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `config/initializers/assets.rb` and add that line to it, like so:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( login.js )
```

Then restart your server and it should work.The code above is all you need in the `assets.rb` file for now.